# How did getter function return the wrong value?

Tags: c++, class

I have defined three files for C++ to implement a class:

color.hpp

```
#ifndef COLOR_HPP
#define COLOR_HPP

class Color {
public: 
    void rset(int rr); // mutator, mutates r_
    void gset(int gg);
    void bset(int bb);
    int rget() const; // accessor, object.r() gets the r channel
    int bget() const;
    int gget() const;

private:
    bool ValidColorValue(int value) const;
    int r_;
    int b_;
    int g_;
    static constexpr int kMaxColorValue = 255;
    static constexpr int kMinColorValue = 0;

};

#endif
```

color.cpp

```
// put by convention, defines methods in color.hpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include "color.hpp"

void Color::rset(int rr) {
    if (ValidColorValue(rr)) {
        r_ == rr;
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Red channel value");
    }
}
void Color::bset(int bb) {
    if (ValidColorValue(bb)) {
        b_ == bb;
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Blue channel value");
    }
}

void Color::gset(int gg) {
    if (ValidColorValue(gg)) {
        g_ == gg;
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Green channel value");
    }
}

int Color::rget() const { return r_; }
int Color::bget() const { return b_; }
int Color::gget() const { return g_; }

bool Color::ValidColorValue(int value) const {
    if (value >= kMinColorValue && value <= kMaxColorValue) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "color.hpp"

int main() {
    Color c;
    c.rset(32);
    std::cout << c.rget() << std::endl;
    c.rset(11);
    std::cout << c.rget() << std::endl; 
}
```

I compiled with the command `g++ color.cpp main.cpp` before typing the command `./a.out`, and I got this result in the command line:

[image]

Strangely enough, when I type in `./a.out` again, I get two different numbers:

[image]

What is going on? How do I get the intended behavior with 32 and then 11 as the output?

Comment: IMHO, you should be using unsigned values, specifically `uint8_t` for your values.  The range of your values is 0...255, which is the range of `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.  There is no point in making them a `signed int`, since your values can't be negative.

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings.  Most compilers ought to have detected that typo.

Comment: Note that usually when you have `if(condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` you can just have `return condition;`.

Answer (score 5):

You neither initialize nor assign the members, so each value is indeterminate. Your getters read the indeterminate values, so the behavior of the program is undefined.

> how do I get intended behavior

You are using the `==` equality operator. Use the `=` assignment operator instead, for example:

```
r_ = rr;
```

Comment: Ah, I mixed up the == and = operator, thanks for pointing that out.